# Создание меню в консольном приложении С++

Tags: c++, linux, консоль, codeblocks

Начал тут писать меню для консольной игры.
Есть несколько пунктов, переход между ними осуществлен с помощью switch. К примеру у меня имеется пункт "Новая игра", как только я выбираю его, у меня выводится просьба ввести имя персонажа и выбрать класс.
Так вот, вопрос такой: вместо использования cin, можно ли сделать выбор по нажатию? Пользуюсь linux и code::blocks. как понимаете библеотеки conio.h тут нету.
Что можно заюзать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: ncurces - окна и ввод для консоли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include  <curses.h>
```

А потом делаешь `getch();`

Эта библиотека вообще-то предназначена для работы с псевдографикой, но ее можно использовать и так.